# import data from sql with datetime to dataframe julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, datetime-format, dataframes.jl

I have table with columns in datetimes format. I want create DataFrame like this:

```
query = "select * from calendar_dict;"

result = DBInterface.execute(connect, query)
result_df = DataFrame(result)
```

but I have error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid number format 2017-01-01 00:00:00

Stacktrace:
  [1] parse(#unused#::Type{DecFP.Dec64}, s::String)
    @ DecFP C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\DecFP\wSrPR\src\DecFP.jl:322
  [2] cast
    @ C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\MySQL\tCDUl\src\execute.jl:50 [inlined]
  [3] cast
    @ C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\MySQL\tCDUl\src\execute.jl:32 [inlined]
  [4] getcolumn(r::MySQL.TextRow{true}, #unused#::Type{Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}}, i::Int64, nm::Symbol)
    @ MySQL C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\MySQL\tCDUl\src\execute.jl:105
  [5] eachcolumns
    @ C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\Tables\T7rHm\src\utils.jl:111 [inlined]
  [6] buildcolumns(schema::Tables.Schema{(:id, :DATA, :ROK, :MIESIAC, :WYM, :OKRES_START, :OKRES_STOP, :OKRES_KSIEGOWY, :MIESIAC_NAZWA, :MIESIAC_ROK, :TYDZIEN_NR, :DZIEN, :DZIEN_TYG, :DZIEN_TYG_NAZWA), Tuple{DecFP.Dec64, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}, Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}}}, rowitr::MySQL.TextCursor{true})
    @ Tables C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\Tables\T7rHm\src\fallbacks.jl:140
  [7] columns
    @ C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\Tables\T7rHm\src\fallbacks.jl:256 [inlined]
  [8] DataFrame(x::MySQL.TextCursor{true}; copycols::Nothing)
    @ DataFrames C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\DataFrames\bza1S\src\other\tables.jl:57
  [9] DataFrame(x::MySQL.TextCursor{true})
    @ DataFrames C:\Users\artur.p\.julia\packages\DataFrames\bza1S\src\other\tables.jl:48
 [10] top-level scope
    @ In[22]:4
 [11] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:368 [inlined]
 [12] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1428
```

Table with data is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V37j4.png)

Comment: Is there any documented suggestion that this type of direct conversion is supported by either package? Issue here stems from incorrect schema, where everything is marked `Union{Missing, DecFP.Dec64}`, which is wrong for, well, every single field in this database. I suspect this needs to supply its own schema, and probably some custom parsing methods due to decimals in `2,017` and such.